# Error code: 85010020 while syncing Google account to mobile device

Tags: google-workspace, google-account, google-apps-sync

I'm trying to sync my Google account, [myid]@gmail.com, with a Windows phone, but I’m getting the error below:

> It looks like you may be using a Google Apps account that is not set
>   up to synchronise with mobile devices. In your PC's web browser, go to
>   Mobile settings for your Google Apps account, enable Google Sync under
>   Service settings and then try to synchronise again.
>
> Error code: 85010020

I have tried to find the mobile settings via http://myaccount.google.com but I can’t seem to find them. How can I enable Google Sync for my Google Apps account?

Comment: See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2805948

Comment: This question may be better off at [windowsphone.se].

Answer (score 1):

From
[Error 85010020 when trying to sync a Google account with Windows Phone](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2805948)

> ## Resolution
>
> Windows Phone was originally designed to use Google Sync (also known as Exchange ActiveSync or EAS) to sync Google email,
> contacts, and calendars. Google has announced that it is ending
> support for Google Sync for new customers on December 31, 2013.
> Because of this, Windows Phone will sync with Google accounts using
> different methods:
>
> - IMAP for email
> - CardDAV for contacts
> - CalDAV for calendars

The referred article include detailed instructions for Windows Phone 7, Windows Phone 8 and "paid Google Apps accounts"

Answer (score 0):

I am using paid Google Apps for Work and it should be working with Google Sync. Firstly, I did it like this:

> 1. First, in your Google Apps administrator control panel, turn on the
>      Enable Google Sync setting. (If you don't have administrator
>      privileges for Google Apps, contact your system administrator.)
> 2. In your web browser on your PC, go to Mobile settings for your Google
>       Apps account, and then enable Google Sync under Service settings.
> 3. On your phone, go to Settings  Settings icon > Email + accounts > Add
>       an account.
> 4. Tap Advanced setup, enter your account email address and password, and
>       then tap Next.
> 5. Tap Exchange ActiveSync.
> 6. Enter the rest of the info for your account:
> 7. Under Domain, enter the last part of the email address for this
>       account—for example, if the email address is yourname@contoso.com,
>       enter contoso.com. Under Server, enter m.google.com. Tap Sign in.

from here: [Sync Google Email Contacts and Calendars FAQ](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp7/people/sync-google-email-contacts-and-calendars-faq)

I was notified via email for *New Device Activation* and I enabled the device in Google Apps console . However, the error was still saying 'not synchronized' on Win Phone.

The solution to sync paid Google Apps for Business on Windows Phone Lumia 535 Windows 8.1 was to set up Google account through "Google" option and not Google Sync account through "Advanced options" like advised from Microsoft (upper link).

When you tap on `Google`, web app will come out to give your phone right to access Gmail, contacts and calendar. Log in and accept permissions and that's it. You will have your Google Apps contacts, calendar and mail synchronized.

[image: photo of menu options]

Comment: Is this answer to the question?

Comment: No, but I can't comment, I must have 50 reputation to comment

Comment: Yes, and you should wait for that. Please do not write anything in answer section except the answer to the question.

Comment: Ok, now it is the answer or workaround, sort of.